# SJF algorithm with arrival time not working properly

Tags: c, algorithm, operating-system

```
typedef struct{
int tL; //Arrival time
int rafaga,id,tE,tP; //burst,id,waitTime,TimeAround     
} process;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
int n= 3;
int i,j,rafagasum=0,k=1,rafagacomp;
process p[n],aux;
char id []= {'A','B','C','D','E','F'};
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    printf(" Process burst %d: ",i);
    scanf("%d",&p[i].rafaga);
    printf("Arrival time %d: ",i);
    scanf("%d",&p[i].tL);
    p[i].id=id[i];



}

//Sort by arrival time

for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
     if(p[i].tL<p[j].tL){
        aux=p[j];
        p[j]=p[i];
        p[i]=aux;


     }

    }
}

for(j=0;j<n;j++){
    rafagasum=rafagasum+p[j].rafaga;
    rafagacomp=p[k].rafaga;
for(i=k;i<n;i++)
{

    if(rafagasum>p[i].tL && p[i].rafaga<rafagacomp)
    aux=p[k];
    p[k]=p[i];
    p[i]=aux;
    }   
    k++;
}
 // We calculate waiting time
p[0].tE=0; 

int sum=0;
for(i=1;i<n;i++){  
sum=sum+p[i-1].rafaga;
p[i].tE=sum-p[i].tL;
}

//We calculate Timearound
    int sum1=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){

    sum1=sum1+p[i].rafaga;
    p[i].tP=sum1-p[i].tL;
}

printf(" ID   Turnaround  TWAit  \n ");

   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("%c \t  %d \t  %d \t  \n", p[i].id,p[i].tP,p[i].tE);
      }



    return 0;
   }
```

I think most of you know what this algorithm (SJF) should do, I was told to code one and this is what I got.
I decided to use a struct "process" which contains the times and id.

I think that the sort by arrival time is working just fine but sometimes, on the printf, I get 2 times the same letter (process)  and the Timearound and Waiting times that I get are not right and I don't really know how to fix that since I think that the formulas I used are right. Any help would be nice.

Wherever it says "rafaga" that means "burst time"

Answer (score 0):

In **SJF** algorithm,first you sort on the basis of *arrival times* **followed** by sorting on the basis of *burst time*.

Now looking at your sorting code, it seems you are using [**selection sort**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort), and your code is not correct. The inner loop always begins from one index more than outer index therefore `j = i + 1`, instead of `j = 0` correct sorting is:

```
for (i = 0;i < n;i++){

    for(j = i+1;j < n;j++)
    {
     if(p[i].tL < p[j].tL){

     aux=p[j];
     p[j]=p[i];
     p[i]=aux;
     }

    }
}
```

Also your sort for `burst time` looks incorrect. Take care of these little things and your code will be correct. On a side note **SJF** is the simplest to code once you understand the basics.

Comment: I've just fixed what you told me, if you could tell me a hint on what's wrong on the burst time sorting that would be really helpfull since I cannot find what's wrong.