# SJF Algorithm in C not working properly

Tags: c, algorithm, process

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct nonpresjf
{
    int at,bt,ft,tat,wt,id;
}nonpresjf;
nonpresjf p[20],p1[20],aux;

int main()
{
    int i,limit,nextval,m,min,j;
    float mediaperm=0,mediaespera=0;
    p[0].wt=p[0].tat=0;
int n=3;

p[0].at=3;
p[1].at=5;
p[2].at=7;

p[0].bt=9;
p[1].bt=3;
p[2].bt=2;



    limit=p[0].at;


    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++){
            if(p[i].at<p[j].at){
                aux=p[j];
                p[j]=p[i];
                p[i]=aux;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        limit+=p[i].bt;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        p1[i]=p[i];
    printf("\n\n Diagram: ");
    printf("%d",p[0].at);
    nextval=p[0].at;
    m=0;
    do
    {
        min = 9999;
        for(i=0;p[i].at<=nextval && i<n ;i++)
            if(p[i].bt<min && p[i].bt>0)
            {
                m=i;
                min=p[i].bt;
            }

        nextval+=p[m].bt;
        p[m].bt=0;
        printf("->P%d->%d",m,nextval);
        if(p[m].bt==0)
        {
            p[m].ft=nextval;
            p[m].tat=p[m].ft-p[m].at;
            p[m].wt=p[m].tat-p1[m].bt;
            p[0].tat+=p[m].tat;
            p[0].wt+=p[m].wt;
        }
    }while(nextval<limit);
    p[0].tat=p[0].tat/n;
    p[0].wt=p[0].wt/n;
    printf("\n\n-----------TABLE-------------------\n");
    printf("\nProcess\tArrival\tBurst\tTurnAround\tWaitTime\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("\nP%d\t%d\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\n",p[i].id,p[i].at,p1[i].bt,p[i].tat,p[i].wt);
    printf("\n\n--------------------------------\n");



    }


    return 0;
}
```

Due to the fact that this is an important assignment and that my other post wasn't answered this is another attemp at programing this.

It seems to be working if arrival times are in order but it goes on an infinite loop randomly with burst times. I debugged it an has something to do with `nextval<limit` nextval never hits limit this happens sometimes.

I think the sort by aT doesn't work properly too, I was suggested in my other post to sort it starting in j=i+1 but that way the theoretically correct output is wrong.

Input:

```
number of process: 3
Arrival Time0: 3
Arrival Time1: 5
Arrival Time2: 7
Burst time 0: 9
Burst time 1: 3
Burst time 2: 2
```

Expected output.

```
-----------TABLE-------------------

Process Arrival Burst   TurnAround      WaitTime
P0      3       9               9               0
P1      5       3               12              9
P2      7       2               7               5
```

---

Actual output.

```
-----------TABLE-------------------

Process Arrival Burst   TurnAround      WaitTime
P0      3       9               9              4
P1      5       3               7              9
P2      7       2               12               5
```

---

If input was:

```
number of process: 3
Arrival Time0: 5
Arrival Time1: 2
Arrival Time2: 7
Burst time 0: 3
Burst time 1: 9
Burst time 2: 2
```

I'd get an infinite loop

Comment: Please note that your loops begin at `1` to index arrays, yet array indexing should be from `0` to `length-1`.

Comment: `for(i=1;i<=n;i++)` C uses zero-offset indexing.

Comment: @wildplasserwhat do you mean by that?

Comment: `@Javi Array indexes go from `0` to `length-1`, not from `1` to `length`.

Comment: @barmar You are right, I didn't remember that, anyway, that doesn't fix anything for me

Comment: Can you simplify the code? Get rid of all the input processing, and just use a pre-defined array with the problem values. Show what the expected output is supposed to be, and what you're getting instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SJF algorithm with arrival time not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48060958/sjf-algorithm-with-arrival-time-not-working-properly)

Comment: Don't you need your sort loops `for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(p[i].at<p[j].at){ …swap… } } }` to be written with `for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)` on the inner loop?

Comment: @barmar Done, I edited it to have more info and the code is now simpler.

Comment: I think you should provide a URL for the SJF (shortest job first) algorithm that you're trying to implement.  I also think you need to explain the role of the `p1` array — and why the output includes the `p1[i].bt` value.   My gut feel is that you are running into problems because you set `p[0].wt=p[0].tat=0;` and `limit=p[0].at;` before you sort the data.  I'm fairly sure that for the general case, you should not set those until after the sorting.  I think you should have coded a function (other than `main()`) that processes a non-preemptive SJF array, and another that prints the array.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler honestly I don't know, this code was written by a mate and he took code from a lot of other SJF that are on the internet, I'm gonna try to program a simpler one using functions and so.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  3) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line. 4) insert appropriate horizontal space: inside parens, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators.

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers. 'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis. I.E. 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 20,  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: the posted code contains: `} return 0;`  however, there is not '{' to match that closing brace.

Comment: regarding: `float mediaperm=0,mediaespera=0;`  1) both those variables are unused.  2) the `=0` is trying to initialize a `float` from a `integer`.  Suggest: `float mediaperm=0.0f,mediaespera=0.0f;